# Pandas for-loop more efficient

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I want to get the different entries of a column of a df, if there are many dfs (with same columns) in a list more efficient like my actuall code. The aim is to prserve all existing IDs of the column 'ID'.
My code works, but i would like it to be more efficient.

```
list_of_dicts = [[{'ID' : A, 
                   'timestamp': '2020-05-10T03:44:50+00:00', 
                   'status': 'online'},
                  {'ID' : A, 
                   'timestamp': '2020-05-10T05:45:50+00:00', 
                   'status': 'online'},
                  {'ID' : B, 
                   'timestamp': '2020-05-10T12:45:50+00:00', 
                   'status': 'online'},
                  {'ID' : C, 
                   'timestamp': '2020-05-10T04:45:50+00:00', 
                   'status': 'online'},
                  {'ID' : A, 
                   'timestamp': '2020-05-10T03:48:50+00:00', 
                   'status': 'offline'}], [{...}{...}...]...]
```

*(the keys of the dicts in the diffrent lists are always the same)*

My Code:

```
stat = []
for i in range(len(list_of_dicts)):
    stat_i = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts[i])
    for x in range(len(stat_i)):
        a = stat_i.loc[x, 'ID']
        if a in stat:
           continue
        else:
           stat.append(a)
```

Expectet output:

```
stat = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a few rows of `list_of_dicts` along with the expected output in **text** format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over your lists and create a single dataframe to get the unique items, you could do this without pandas as well.

using a list comprehension.

```
stat = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(item) for item in list_of_dicts])['ID'].unique()
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```